# How to deal with CMS style HTML fields and malformed HTML

Tags: html, django, content-management-system

I have a text field on my Django site that allows certain users to insert HTML and text, and I want to make sure that the inserted text does not mess with the code outside of the `<div>` that contains the text.

For instance, if I accidentally specify "</div>" without an opening tag, I wouldn't want the textfield to malform/escape out of the parent `<div>`.

What is the best way to deal with this? I want to continue to allow full HTML on this field at the moment as I only use it personally to create posts.

Comment: I think Django escapes by default. So it won't render the HTML unless you mark it as "safe". Is that right?

Comment: yes but I'm using the `safe` function in my template output to output the raw html